# I want to display an error message on top and bottom of a Visualforce page using Apex. How to do so?

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages, pagemessages

We have used this code previously for showing error, but now we want to show the error on top and on the bottom of the page:

```
ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, System.Label.CustomLabel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're free to include multiple `<apex:pageMessages />` components, positioned wherever on the page you want.

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:commandButton action="{! addErrors }" title="Test" value="Test"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

with the controller

```
public PageReference addErrors() {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Test'));
    return null;
}
```

yields

[image: Visualforce page screenshot]

Simply add more `<apex:pageMessages />` components wherever you need to display your current page's errors.